# How to embedd an SVG File into another SVG

Tags: svg

I want to reference another SVG file in my main SVG file and show it there.

The "svg1.svg":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg id="main"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    viewBox="0 0 512 512">
    <path id="testPath"
        d="M 100 350 q 150 -300 300 0"
        stroke="blue"
        fill="none" />
</svg>
```

The "referencing.svg":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <g transform="translate(20,20)">
        <circle r="10"
            stroke="black"
            fill-opacity="20%" />
        <use xlink:href="svg1.svg#main"
            x="10" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

The referencing.svg should show the content of the svg1.svg but its not showing up at all. Both Svg-Files are in the same local Folder.
The validator at https://validator.w3.org/check says the Syntax is correct.

Am I missing something or does it not work like this at all?

Comment: And you're hosting these files on a webserver?

Comment: I just have them local on my system and they never get on a server. I just need it for myself so no server needed. I want to open the files in my browser locally.

Comment: You can't due to the browser's security model. One local file cannot reference/load another local file. If you're developing web pages then you need to use a webserver.